# jquery validation plugin for checkbox- at least one selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for form fields validation. I have multiple checkboxes in the form. I tried couple of different ways for the logic 'at least one need to be selected' but nothing is working but when i try something out of validation plugin its working fine with this code. If you can tell me how i can incorporate this below code within validation plugin

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

      if(!checked) {
         // <form:errors path="chk" cssClass="errors" element="div" />
         $(".form-error").text("* You must check at least one checkbox.").show();
       // alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");
        return false;
      }

    });
});
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script>


  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#myForm").validate({



      rules: {
          crcode: "required",
          dtype: "required",
          pview: "required",
          prview: "required",


      },

      messages: {
          crcode: "Rate code is required",
          dtype: "Dwell type is required",
          pview: "Public view is required",
          prview: "Private view is required",


      }

      });
      });

  </script>
Here are my checkboxes
 <div class="[ form-group ]" style="font-family: KlavikaWebBasicBold;" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="fancy-checkbox-default1" autocomplete="off" class="fancy" />
            <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-default1" class="[ btn btn-default ]">
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                    <span> </span>
                </label>
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-default1" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                   Video+Internet
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="[ form-group ]" style="font-family: KlavikaWebBasicBold;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="fancy-checkbox-default2" autocomplete="off"  class="fancy" />
            <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-default2" class="[ btn btn-default ]">
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                    <span> </span>
                </label>
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-default2" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                   Video+Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="[ form-group ]" style="font-family: KlavikaWebBasicBold;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="fancy-checkbox-default3" autocomplete="off" class="fancy" />
            <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-default3" class="[ btn btn-default ]">
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                    <span> </span>
                </label>
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-default3" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                   Video+Security
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if you can tell me how I can incorporate this below code within validation plugin

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (!checked) { ....
```

You don't.

That code makes no sense for use with jQuery Validate plugin and **can be removed entirely**.  When using the jQuery Validate plugin, you do not need to write a wholly independent function for checkbox validation, **NOR do you need a click handler of any kind**.

You simply need to declare the `required` rule on the checkbox name and the plugin will automatically make at least one checkbox required.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#myForm").validate({
          rules: {
              chkbox: "required", // <- add this
              crcode: "required",
              dtype: "required",
              pview: "required",
              prview: "required",
          },
          messages: {
              chkbox: "* You must check at least one checkbox.", // <- add this
              crcode: "Rate code is required",
              dtype: "Dwell type is required",
              pview: "Public view is required",
              prview: "Private view is required",
          }
      });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/42t2twLo/**

Exact placement of this checkbox error message can be facilitated with [the `errorPlacement` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement).

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.is(":checkbox")) {
        error.insertBefore(element);  // custom placement example
    } else { 
        error.insertAfter(element);   // default placement
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine when i try alone only this section of the form on jsfiddle but its not working when i try to submit entire form.. something is blocking the checkbox validation and remaining validation working fine not sure what causing the problem

Comment: Can you let me know what will be the possible reasons for why its not working only for checkbox validation when i do submit entire form

Comment: @uidev, I only know what you've shown in your OP is working fine, and that you should not write additional code in lieu of fixing root problems.  You'll have to carefully compare your code to the jsFiddle and look for any differences.

Comment: I like to know if validate() method and the function with click event need to be triggered at the same time so that the output will appear at same time how i can do that. right now click event is firing before validate method

Comment: @uidev, what click event?  I already showed you that you do not need to capture the click nor need any of your code associated with it.  The `.validate()` method is used for initialization and only needs to be called once on DOM ready.  Just follow the code that's used in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Finally resolved the problem, custom css on those checkboxes is hiding those by default and as validation plugin will not work on hidden fields so thats why its not worked for me yesterday but i resolved it

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this if my `name` element is not the same for each checkbox? (ie i'm appending a digit as an iterator)

Comment: @joey8oro, you're not supposed to use comments section to ask new questions.  If you have searched SO and can't find an answer, then please post a new question.