# Validate that at least one check box is checked using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate that at least one check box in a group of check boxes is selected.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897717/6461693) answer get's me very close to what I need, but the hitch is that I do not want to change the name attribute in the html, because in my case the names are unique and crucial to data-binding.

I have also tried the following, but it results in each checkbox being required instead of one or more.

```
$('.chkbox').each(function(){
       $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Select 1 or more categories."
            }
        })
    });
```

**EDIT -** Here is the HTML markup of a single checkbox

```
<div class="form-control">
    <input id="DocTypesGroup_0__IsSelected" name="DocTypesGroup[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="DocTypesGroup[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label>
        Type 1
    </label>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: can we see the markup?  It'd help to see what "add" is applied to and the heirarchy of the elements.  Also, could you use a hidden input that checks to see if any checkbox is checked, and then apply the rules to the hidden input?

Comment: @JoeFitzsimmons I've added the html markup. I like the idea of a hidden input that tracks whether or not a checkbox is checked. I will try that and check back.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working for my purposes based on a helpful comment on the question.

I added a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="CategoryTrack" name="CategoryTrack" />
```

and used some jquery code to track my check boxes, and set the value of the hidden field

```
$('.chkbox[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var i = 0;

    $('.chkbox[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            i++;
        }
    });

    if (i > 0) {
        $('#CategoryTrack').val(true);
    }
    else {
        $('#CategoryTrack').val('');
    }

    $("#Form").valid();
});
```

Finally, here is the validation method

```
$('#BriefForm').validate({
        ignore: [], //need this to validate hidden fields
        ...
        rules: {
            'CategoryTrack': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'CategoryTrack': 'At least one category must be checked'
        }
    });
```

I included this to note that by default, a hidden field won't be validated. So don't forget to include the `ignore: []` line.